# Как отфильтровать максимальное значение в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Всем привет!
Совсем недавно в программировании на питоне, хочу найти максимальное значение в списке , используя filter(). Не могли бы вы помочь с этим?

Пробовала делать так:

```
  n=[1,2,3,4]
  f=filter(lambda x: max(x),n)
  print(f)
```

но выводит:

```
<filter object at 0x00000242B2220DC0>
```

Comment: Можете просто использовать max(n)

Comment: Зачем использовать более сложный и медленный вариант, если есть гораздо более простой и быстрый? Как вам правильно сказали - filter не для того.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, это нужно в учебных целях. Тогда примерно так:

```
n = [1,2,3,4]
f = filter(lambda x: x == max(n), n)
print(*f)
# 4
```

- Нужно прописать условие фильтра, т.е. равенство элемента максимальному
- Нужно получить значение из фильтра, как-то по нему проитерировавшись

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю filter() не для того чтобы искать максимальный элемент. Эта функция для отсечки из набора значений по критерию из функции. Но если прям очень хочется реализовать максимальное значение (даже если при этом не прочь поизвращаться), тогда:

```
def el_in_lst(val):
    return True if val==maximal else False
n = [1, 2, 3, 4]
maximal = max(n)
print(int(list(filter(el_in_lst,[i for i in n]))[0]))
```

P.S.: Думаю еще больше извратиться нельзя будет =)

Comment: 1) `[i for i in n]` зачем вообще, это тоже самое, что просто `n`. 2) Отдельная функция для условия нисколько не понятнее, чем если `lambda` написать, для коротких функций `lambda` как-то уместнее даже. 3) `return val==maximal` достаточно, тернарный оператор не нужен.

Comment: @CrazyElf, я же написал, что по максимому сделал извращение =) Это же очевидно что с лямбдой лучше

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем множить сущности сверх того, что уже умножил автор вопроса )